# programming language regular expression for arithmetic expressions

Tags: regex

I'm wondering if anyone knew what was the regular expression used to parse an arithmetic expression (with functions and all) of any programming language(c or c++ if possible)?, for a project we need to find one from a real programming language, but I can't find one.

Comment: lazy programmer is right

Comment: Arithmetic expressions are hierarchical in nature, you can't parse them with a regular language like basic regex.

Comment: Maybe Google 'Backus Naur' form?  Some language grammars are expressed using this.  It's not a regex as such, but getting closer.

Answer (score 2):

These aren't regular expressions, since regular expressions don't have enough power to parse this.

What compilers use is a *context-free grammar* or for [C++.](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/) even a context-sensitive grammar.

**Why?**

Programming expressions can be cascaded: you can for instance write an `if` in an `if` in an `if` in an ... Now a regular expression has no means to handle hierarcy.

Programming languages use *grammar*: a set of rules that describe how a language is shaped. For instance:

```
<expression> -> <if-expression>
<expression> -> "a = 0;"
<if-expression> -> if <condition> then <expression> fi
<condition> -> "a == b"
```

(simple example grammar).

Now based on that grammar, one can derive:

```
if a == b then
    if a == b then
        a = 0;
    fi
fi
```

The first step in a compiler is to build an *abstract syntax tree*: something like:

```
if
├── a == b
└── if
    ├── a == b
    └── a = 0;
```

Which is shaped by parsing the rules backwards.

[**This**](http://www.nongnu.org/hcb/) document for instance describes the grammar of C++.

Comment: reuglar experssions can define any algebric language ,no? and programming languages are algebric languages

Comment: Well except if you disable cascading effects. It can parse for instance polynomial expressions. But from the moment you have something like brackets, it can't

Comment: algebric languages are context free languages, you're saying that you need a stack automata , but i think regular expressions do define that (sorry for bad english)

Comment: No, every regular expression has an equivalent finite state machine (and vice versa), and every contex-free grammar has a push-down (or stack) automaton and vice versa. That's the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#Summary).